# How can I go about finding points where there is a bend/cut in my data?

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, curve

I have the following data points: There are 5 sublists in this list of data. What I am trying to do is find the points where there is a maximum amount of curvature.

```
for i in range(len(smallest_5)):
    x = [x for x,y in smallest_5[i]]
    y = [y for x,y in smallest_5[i]]
    plt.scatter(x,y)
    plt.savefig('bend'+str(count)+'.png')
    plt.show()
```

I've used this code to plot the points.

```
sub_curvature = []
for i in range(len(smallest_5)):
    a = np.array(smallest_5[i])

    dx_dt = np.gradient(a[:,0])
    dy_dt = np.gradient(a[:,1])
    velocity = np.array([ [dx_dt[i], dy_dt[i]] for i in range(dx_dt.size)])

    ds_dt = np.sqrt(dx_dt * dx_dt + dy_dt * dy_dt)

    tangent = np.array([1/ds_dt] * 2).transpose() * velocity

    tangent_x = tangent[:, 0]
    tangent_y = tangent[:, 1]

    deriv_tangent_x = np.gradient(tangent_x)
    deriv_tangent_y = np.gradient(tangent_y)

    dT_dt = np.array([ [deriv_tangent_x[i], deriv_tangent_y[i]] for i in range(deriv_tangent_x.size)])

    length_dT_dt = np.sqrt(deriv_tangent_x * deriv_tangent_x + deriv_tangent_y * deriv_tangent_y)

    normal = np.array([1/length_dT_dt] * 2).transpose() * dT_dt

    d2s_dt2 = np.gradient(ds_dt)
    d2x_dt2 = np.gradient(dx_dt)
    d2y_dt2 = np.gradient(dy_dt)

    curvature = np.abs(d2x_dt2 * dy_dt - dx_dt * d2y_dt2) / (dx_dt * dx_dt + dy_dt * dy_dt)**1.5
    t_component = np.array([d2s_dt2] * 2).transpose()
    n_component = np.array([curvature * ds_dt * ds_dt] * 2).transpose()

    acceleration = t_component * tangent + n_component * normal

    sub_curvature.append(curvature)
```

I used the code above to calculate the curvature of individual points on the data. [image]
[image]
[image]

Above are some of the graphs I created using the data. As you can see, the first one has no real bend but the last two have a point where there is a large bend. How could I go about identifying this region? Is it correct to calculate the curvature for individual points or should I look at the curvature over a sliding window of points? Thank you!

Comment: Part of the problem here is terminology: I understand curves, and maths, but I don't understand what you mean with "bend", so let's fix that. Let's ignore "bend" entirely and go back to curvature: we can imagine drawing a curve through your points, and then fitting a circle to that curve, such that the tangent of the curve matches the tangent of the circle at the point they intersect - we can slide that circle and it'll grow and shrink, and might even flip from one side of the curve to that other. What are you looking for?  "where the circle is smallest"? "where it flips"? something else?

Comment: I think that answering this mathematically has the best chance of being portable. Let's suppose you wanted to find where the graphs deviate from a parabolic path. You will want to fit a curve to your data (assuming it is modeling a continuous function) and then find where additional forces are applied.  This would actually be a third derivative. Note that this will not necessarily be exactly at one of your points.

Answer (score 2):

If we assume "curvature" to mean circular curvature, then you'll need a sliding window over 3 points (since 3 points determine a circle).

For any three points `(a,b,c)` the curvature is `2 * |(a-b) x (b-c)| / (|a-b| * |b-c| * |c-b|)`.

We can get `a-b` and `b-c` from

```
ab = smallest_5[1:] - smallest_5[:-1]
```

and `a-c` from:

```
ac = smallest_5[2:] - smallest_5[:-2]
```

Then the squared curvature is:

```
curv_sq = 4 * (np.cross(ab[1:], ab[:-1])**2).sum() / ((ab[1:]**2).sum() * (ab[:-1]**2).sum() * (ac**2).sum())
```

Since we're just looking for a maximum curvature, we don't actually have to take the square root of that. We can find the index of the point with maximum curvature with

```
max_curv_index = np.argmax(curv_sq)
```

Answer (score 1):

As an idea, you can find the minimum `y` which is not the first or the last value in the y-dimension of the array. For example:

```
s4 = np.array(smallest_5[4]).T # exctract a sub-array
min_y = np.agrmin(s4[1]) # gives 13
min_y == (0 or len(s4[1]-1) # gives False, so the minimum is in the middle of the curve

s0 = np.array(smallest_5[0]).T # exctract a sub-array
min_y = np.agrmin(s0[1]) # gives 16
min_y == (0 or len(s0[1]-1) # gives True, so the minimum is not in the middle of the curve
```